# Installation issues with openresty

Tags: nginx, lua, openresty

My machine has Mac os. In this I have nginx 1.6.x. I initially installed with Homebrew.

I am trying to run a project which in production uses openresty (as it has lua 3rd party modules)

My confusion is regarding which one to install.

Do I need to completely remove nginx and install openresty, as it's documentation says it's a bundle of components,i.e. it will contain nginx?

or

Install new version of nginx with lua 3rd party modules and then install openresty too.

Sorry if there is a or too many typo in my question.

A good link will be helpful as I think I have confused myself enough.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Openresty is nginx bundled with lua and other 3rd party modules, so having both of them installed on your computer may lead to trouble, for example:

This case can happen if you try to run both of them at the same time: Your nginx conf file can have a server block listening to a port while your openresty also have a server block listening to that block. If nginx is already running, openresty won't be able to run, since the port is already bound.

I installed openresty with a previous installation of nginx and ran into some problems, so i would advise you to save relevant configuration and data from your nginx instalation and removing it.

Installing openresty seems better since besides installing nginx, it will install lua modules and a few more as it is listed on their github.https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module

I don't know how your project is going, but i would suggest moving using openresty, since it will save potential trouble.